# Returning file/files in JSON response (Java-Jersey-ReST)

Tags: java, json, rest, download, jersey-2.0

I am working on a use case where I am displaying user's messages on a JSP. Details of the flow are:

- All the messages will be shown in a table with icon for attachments
- When the user clicks on attachment, the file should get downloaded.
- If there is more than one attachment, user can select the required
  one to download.
- The attachments will be stored on the local filesystem and the path for the attachments will be determined by the system.

I have tried to implement by referring to these SO questions:

- [Input and Output binary streams using JERSEY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496209/input-and-output-binary-streams-using-jersey)
- [Return a file using Java Jersey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900611/return-a-file-using-java-jersey)
- [file downloading in restful web services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10100936/file-downloading-in-restfull-web-services)

However, it's not solving my purpose. I have the following questions:

1. Is it possible to send message data (like subject, message, message id, etc) along with the attachments (Inputstream) in one response?
2. If yes, what needs to be the `MediaType` for `@Produces` annotation in my resource method? Currently my resource is annotated with `@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)`. Will this work?
3. How to send the file data in the response?

Any pointers appreciated. TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can add custom data to the response Header, so yes you are able to send such message data. Add the data to the response Header.
2. `@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)` will not work, unless the clients will accept JSON as a file, what they should and will not do ;)

   The correct `MediaType` depends on what kind of file you want to submit.

   You can use the default MediaType / MIME-Type `MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM` / `application/octet-stream` ([Is there a “default”
   MIME type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12539058/is-there-a-default-mime-type)) but I think it's better to use the correct and exact MIME-Type for your file.
3. You will find working examples for sending file data with jersey in [Input and Output binary streams using JERSEY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496209/input-and-output-binary-streams-using-jersey) - so there is no need to answer this again :)

Hope this was helpful somehow, have a nice day.