# How to deliver .jad file using Jersey Rest service?

Tags: java, java-me, jersey, jad

I have to return a JavaME .jad file from restful web service (using Jersey), which is then used to install an app on a mobile phone. Before delivering the .jad file some values in there have to be changed. I was thinking of reading the original file, change the read input and writing it back to some outputstream. Can I just return the output stream in a Jersey Rest services? Is there anything special I have to take of in terms of mime-type, etc.? Does anyone know of some kind of example code or tutorial for this purpose?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Either like here: 
[Input and Output binary streams using JERSEY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496209/input-and-output-binary-streams-using-jersey)
or you could send the StreamingOutput as an entity like this:

```
return Response.ok(streamingOutput).type("text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor");
```

Point is you have to use the `OutputStream` handed to you via the `StreamingOutput.write(OutputStream outputStream)` method.

Comment: Thanks, I had found that topic already but was looking for a code example how to implement and call the StreamingOutputs write method.
But I think I got it running now. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad I could help. How about closing the topic? :-)

Comment: Just set my answer as the correct :-) not sure how, I answer more than i ask.