# Give the option to save the image

Tags: java, html, image

My service call returns the image.

It returns the png image and it has content-type in header as image/jpeg , it opens the image in the same page. I want to give the option to the user to save this image to the disk.

Comment: You need `Content-Disposition` header in server's response

Comment: Thanks. Is there any example , on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `Content-Disposition` header in server's response

[For example](http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/how-do-i-prompt-a-save-as-dialog-for-an-accepted-mime-type.html)

Comment: Thanks for the example. Well here I am using jersey web services of java and dont know how to do that here in.

Comment: May be this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496209/input-and-output-binary-streams-using-jersey

Comment: Look at this lines: `return Response
            .ok(docStream, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
            .header("content-disposition","attachment; filename = doc.rtf")
            .build();`

Comment: But  @GET
    @Produces("image/jpeg")
    public byte[] , this is my code , still it opens in same browser.

Comment: You should return `Response`, not `byte[]` and return it like in my previous comment

Answer (score 1):

Content-Disposition may be inline, specify content-disposition as attachement

```
response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + imageName + ".jpg");
```