# How to use Jersey in a restlet for download?

Tags: java, jersey

I am playing around with Jersey and would like to know how one should implement a "download" feature. For example let's say I have some resources under `/files/` that I would like to be "downloaded" via a `GET` how should I do this? I already know the proper annotations and implementations for `GET`, `PUT`, `POST`, `DELETE`, but I'm not quite sure how one should treat binary data in this case. Could somebody please point me in the right direction, or show me a simple implementation? I've had a look at the `jersey-samples-1.4`, but I can't seem to be able to find what I am looking for.

Many thanks!

Comment: Aren't jersey and restlet different implementations of the REST API? If so, I don't understand why would you want to use both at the same time. Perhaps you meant `REST` and not `Restlet`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use @Produces annotation to specify which media type file is (pdf, zip, etc..). Java specification for this annotation can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19226-01/820-7627/gipxf/index.html).

Your server should return created file. For example in core java you can do something like this:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
@Path("path")
public StreamingOutput getFile() {
    return new StreamingOutput() {
        public void write(OutputStream out) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
            try {
                 FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(my_file);
                 byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                 int length;
                 while ((length = in.read(buffer)) > 0){
                    out.write(buffer, 0, length);
                 }
                 in.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new WebApplicationException(e);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks! How about the case where I don't have the file type in advance, but know it's a binary? I assume the `@Produces` is on the method? (Sorry, would you mind just illustrating it in a method with the proper annotations? I know how to handle the streaming part...)

Comment: OK, I edited my post. Now, you have method example. I think that you should use APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM if your file is binary. In this example I have used post http://stackoverflow.com/a/3503704/987847

Comment: I was playing around with the code you provided and I seem to be getting a `returned a response status of 405 Method Not Allowed`. Any ideas...? On the client-side I have `WebResource webResource = client.resource(url);
webResource.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM).get(String.class)`

Comment: You must specify which HTTP method will implemented service serve. For example I used @GET annotation to specify that for specific "path" and GET HTTP request this method (service) will be executed.

Comment: It turned out I had a typo in the @Path and that screwed everything up. Otherwise the code was alright. Thanks anyway!