# How to download a file using a Java REST service and a data stream

Tags: java, rest, download, jersey, bytestream

> I have 3 machines:
>
> 1. server where the file is located
> 2. server where REST service is running ( Jersey)
> 3. client(browser) with access to 2nd server but no access to 1st server

How can I directly (without saving the file on 2nd server) download the file from 1st server to client's machine? 
From 2nd server I can get a **ByteArrayOutputStream** to get the file from 1st server, can I pass this stream further to the client using the REST service?

It will work this way?

So basically what I want to achieve is to allow the client to download a file from 1st server using the REST service on 2nd server (since there is no direct access from client to 1st server) using only data streams (so no data touching the file system of 2nd server).

What I try now with EasyStream library:

```
final FTDClient client = FTDClient.getInstance();

try {
    final InputStreamFromOutputStream <String> isOs = new InputStreamFromOutputStream <String>() {
        @Override
        public String produce(final OutputStream dataSink) throws Exception {
            return client.downloadFile2(location, Integer.valueOf(spaceId), URLDecoder.decode(filePath, "UTF-8"), dataSink);
        }
    };
    try {
        String fileName = filePath.substring(filePath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);

        StreamingOutput output = new StreamingOutput() {
            @Override
            public void write(OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
                int length;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                while ((length = isOs.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }
                outputStream.flush();
            }
        };
        return Response.ok(output, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
            .header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"")
            .build();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE2**

So my code now with the custom MessageBodyWriter looks simple:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(2048) ;
client.downloadFile(location, spaceId, filePath, baos);
return Response.ok(baos).build();
```

But I get the same heap error when trying with large files.

**UPDATE3**
Finally managed to get it working !
StreamingOutput did the trick.

Thank you @peeskillet ! Many thanks !

Answer (score 39, accepted):

> "How can I directly (without saving the file on 2nd server) download the file from 1st server to client's machine?"

Just use the `Client` API and get the `InputStream` from the response

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
String url = "...";
final InputStream responseStream = client.target(url).request().get(InputStream.class);
```

There are two flavors to get the `InputStream`. You can also use

```
Response response = client.target(url).request().get();
InputStream is = (InputStream)response.getEntity();
```

Which one is the more efficient? I'm not sure, but the returned `InputStream`s are different classes, so you may want to look into that if you care to.

> From 2nd server I can get a ByteArrayOutputStream to get the file from 1st server, can I pass this stream further to the client using the REST service?

So most of the answers you'll see in the [link provided by @GradyGCooper](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3496209/2587435) seem to favor the use of `StreamingOutput`. An example implementation might be something like

```
final InputStream responseStream = client.target(url).request().get(InputStream.class);
System.out.println(responseStream.getClass());
StreamingOutput output = new StreamingOutput() {
    @Override
    public void write(OutputStream out) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {  
        int length;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        while((length = responseStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        out.flush();
        responseStream.close();
    }   
};
return Response.ok(output).header(
        "Content-Disposition", "attachment, filename=\"...\"").build();
```

But if we look at the [source code for StreamingOutputProvider](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-common/2.16/org/glassfish/jersey/message/internal/StreamingOutputProvider.java#StreamingOutputProvider.writeTo%28javax.ws.rs.core.StreamingOutput%2Cjava.lang.Class%2Cjava.lang.reflect.Type%2Cjava.lang.annotation.Annotation[]%2Cjavax.ws.rs.core.MediaType%2Cjavax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap%2Cjava.io.OutputStream%29), you'll see in the `writeTo`, that it simply writes the data from one stream to another. So with our implementation above, we have to write twice.

How can we get only one write? Simple return the `InputStream` as the `Response`

```
final InputStream responseStream = client.target(url).request().get(InputStream.class);
return Response.ok(responseStream).header(
        "Content-Disposition", "attachment, filename=\"...\"").build();
```

If we look at the [source code for InputStreamProvider](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-common/2.16/org/glassfish/jersey/message/internal/AbstractMessageReaderWriterProvider.java#AbstractMessageReaderWriterProvider.writeTo%28java.io.InputStream%2Cjava.io.OutputStream%29), it simply delegates to [`ReadWriter.writeTo(in, out)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-common/2.16/org/glassfish/jersey/message/internal/ReaderWriter.java#ReaderWriter.writeTo%28java.io.InputStream%2Cjava.io.OutputStream%29), which simply does what we did above in the `StreamingOutput` implementation

```
 public static void writeTo(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    int read;
    final byte[] data = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    while ((read = in.read(data)) != -1) {
        out.write(data, 0, read);
    }
}
```

**Asides:**

- `Client` objects are expensive resources. You may want to reuse the same `Client` for request. You can extract a `WebTarget` from the client for each request.

  ```
  WebTarget target = client.target(url);
  InputStream is = target.request().get(InputStream.class);
  ```

  I think the `WebTarget` can even be shared. I can't find anything in the [Jersey 2.x documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/client.html#d0e5011) (only because it is a larger document, and I'm too lazy to scan through it right now :-), but in the [Jersey 1.x documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.19/client-api.html#d4e621), it says the `Client` and `WebResource` (which is equivalent to `WebTarget` in 2.x) can be shared between threads. So I'm guessing Jersey 2.x would be the same. but you may want to confirm for yourself.
- You don't have to make use of the `Client` API. A download can be easily achieved with the `java.net` package APIs. But since you're already using Jersey, it doesn't hurt to use its APIs
- The above is assuming Jersey 2.x. For Jersey 1.x, a simple Google search should get you a bunch of hits for working with the API (or the documentation I linked to above)

---

## UPDATE

I'm such a dufus. While the OP and I are contemplating ways to turn a `ByteArrayOutputStream` to an `InputStream`, I missed the simplest solution, which is simply to write a `MessageBodyWriter` for the `ByteArrayOutputStream`

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Provider
public class OutputStreamWriter implements MessageBodyWriter<ByteArrayOutputStream> {

    @Override
    public boolean isWriteable(Class<?> type, Type genericType,
            Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        return ByteArrayOutputStream.class == type;
    }

    @Override
    public long getSize(ByteArrayOutputStream t, Class<?> type, Type genericType,
            Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        return -1;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeTo(ByteArrayOutputStream t, Class<?> type, Type genericType,
            Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType,
            MultivaluedMap<String, Object> httpHeaders, OutputStream entityStream)
            throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
        t.writeTo(entityStream);
    }
}
```

Then we can simply return the `ByteArrayOutputStream` in the response

```
return Response.ok(baos).build();
```

D'OH!

#### UPDATE 2

Here are the tests I used (

Resource class

```
@Path("test")
public class TestResource {

    final String path = "some_150_mb_file";

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
    public Response doTest() throws Exception {
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(path);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int len;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        while ((len = is.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1) {
            baos.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
        System.out.println("Server size: " + baos.size());
        return Response.ok(baos).build();
    }
}
```

Client test

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        String url = "http://localhost:8080/api/test";
        Response response = client.target(url).request().get();
        String location = "some_location";
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(location);
        InputStream is = (InputStream)response.getEntity();
        int len = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        while((len = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        is.close();
    }
}
```

#### UPDATE 3

So the final solution for this particular use case was for the OP to simply pass the `OutputStream` from the `StreamingOutput`'s `write` method. Seems the third-party API, required a `OutputStream` as an argument.

```
StreamingOutput output = new StreamingOutput() {
    @Override
    public void write(OutputStream out) {
        thirdPartyApi.downloadFile(.., .., .., out);
    }
}
return Response.ok(output).build();
```

Not quite sure, but seems the reading/writing within the resource method, using ByteArrayOutputStream`, realized something into memory.

The point of the `downloadFile` method accepting an `OutputStream` is so that it can write the result directly to the `OutputStream` provided. For instance a `FileOutputStream`, if you wrote it to file, while the download is coming in, it would get directly streamed to the file.

It's not meant for us to keep a reference to the `OutputStream`, as you were trying to do with the `baos`, which is where the memory realization comes in.

So with the way that works, we are writing directly to the response stream provided for us. The method `write` doesn't actually get called until the `writeTo` method (in the `MessageBodyWriter`), where the `OutputStream` is passed to it.

You can get a better picture looking at the `MessageBodyWriter` I wrote. Basically in the `writeTo` method, replace the `ByteArrayOutputStream` with `StreamingOutput`, then inside the method, call `streamingOutput.write(entityStream)`. You can see the link I provided in the earlier part of the answer, where I link to the `StreamingOutputProvider`. This is exactly what happens

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75834/discussion-on-answer-by-peeskillet-how-to-download-a-file-using-a-java-rest-serv).

Comment: You are not a dufus!

Answer (score 0):

See example here: [Input and Output binary streams using JERSEY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496209/input-and-output-binary-streams-using-jersey)

Pseudo code would be something like this (there are a few other similar options in above mentioned post):

```
@Path("file/")
@GET
@Produces({"application/pdf"})
public StreamingOutput getFileContent() throws Exception {
     public void write(OutputStream output) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
        try {
          //
          // 1. Get Stream to file from first server
          //
          while(<read stream from first server>) {
              output.write(<bytes read from first server>)
          }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new WebApplicationException(e);
        } finally {
              // close input stream
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: while(<read stream from first server>) {
              output.write(<bytes read from first server>)
          }
Does this read the bytes into Memory or directly write it into the outputstream?

Answer (score 0):

Refer this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="download", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public void getDownload(HttpServletResponse response) {

// Get your file stream from wherever.
InputStream myStream = someClass.returnFile();

// Set the content type and attachment header.
response.addHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=myfilename.txt");
response.setContentType("txt/plain");

// Copy the stream to the response's output stream.
IOUtils.copy(myStream, response.getOutputStream());
response.flushBuffer();
}
```

Details at: https://twilblog.github.io/java/spring/rest/file/stream/2015/08/14/return-a-file-stream-from-spring-rest.html

Comment: Not helpful! Also the detail page lacks information

Comment: I don't understand this answer at all.