# making users download a file from another server in a web application

Tags: javascript, java

I have a java web application running on Websphere App Server and I want my users to download a file from another server at some certain point in my application.

For example when the user is at http://www.a.com, I want him to download http://www.b.com/file.txt without his interaction. I know that it is not possible via javascript because of CORS and so far, I could just think of Java applets.

Can you suggest me any other way to make my users download a file from another server without interaction? After he downloads the file, I am going to get this file to my own server(http://www.a.com)

Thank you

Comment: the servlet itself could ftp the file from b.com and then you could stream it from a.com unless it is static then you could just reference it from your HTML

Comment: @ScaryWombat Thank you for your comment, but I want the user to download it, otherwise b. com will see a.com' s IP at all requests. The user himself should be the one who is requesting the file. And file is not served by FTP protocol. It is served on a web page so I should download it with HTTP request.

Comment: so why not just include it as a `href` on your html ?

Comment: @ScaryWombat if i did that, user will download this file to his PC that' s ok, but how am i going to get this file from his PC without his interaction?

Comment: Hope this can help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29712554/how-to-download-a-file-using-a-java-rest-service-and-a-data-stream

Comment: @Anthony this is a completely different scenario, in fact. What i want is to make the user download a file from a different source, but here, they are trying to achieve server-to-server file downloading