# How to create a zip file from the response received as part of rest call

Tags: java, zip

As part of my project i am making a rest call which gives the response as a zip file .
In rest client i am getting the response in some big unreadable format. 
the zip will be containing more than one file ( the name of these files will be different ) every time .
Can you please suggest me how to read this data and convert it into the zip files which will contain all files .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to download a file using a Java REST service and a data stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29712554/how-to-download-a-file-using-a-java-rest-service-and-a-data-stream)

Answer (score 0):

Make the rest api return the URL to the zip. Then you should stream it as a normal file and then you can use a library to unpack  the zip.