# Direct download of a blob from server

Tags: java, mongodb, blob, restful-url, gridfs

I wrote a Restful webservice with MongoDB. This is my code :

```
@GET
@Path("/download/{id}/")
@Produces("application/epub")
public Response getImagefile(@PathParam("content") String content,
        @PathParam("id") String imageID) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
    String urlContent = "D:\\NetbeansWorkspace\\Webservice\\web\\download\\image.jpg";
    GridFSDBFile findImage;
        DB db = getConnection().getDB(content);
        GridFS gfsImage = new GridFS(db, "image");
        findImage = gfsImage.findOne(new ObjectId(imageID));
        findImage.writeTo(urlContent);
        File file = new File(urlContent);
        ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok((Object) urlContent);
        response.header("Content-Disposition",
                "attachment; filename=" + "image.jpg");
        return response.build();

}
```

I am extracting an image from a server and providing a link to it for a download. This code does this not very efficiently by saving it to urlContent (my local file) first and then making it available for download. I would like to skip saving to urlContent part and provide a link which extracts and downloads a blob image directly from the server. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496209/input-and-output-binary-streams-using-jersey) has a good example on how to do it, although it is about pdf files (it shouldn't make any difference). In a nutshell, the service should return a `StreamingOutput`, which is basically a wrapper around an `OutputStream`.

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496209/input-and-output-binary-streams-using-jersey/12573173#12573173) there is an even more complete example, which uses the `StreamingOutput` as the entity of a `Response`.

Answer (score 0):

**FIXED**

```
@GET
@Path("/download/{id}/")
@Produces("application/epub")
public Response getImagefile(@PathParam("content") String content,
        @PathParam("id") String imageID) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {

        GridFSDBFile findImage;
        DB db = getConnection().getDB(content);
        GridFS gfsImage = new GridFS(db, "image");
        findImage = gfsImage.findOne(new ObjectId(imageID));
        String filename = findImage.getFilename();
        ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok((Object) findImage.getInputStream());
        response.header("Content-Disposition",
                "attachment; filename=" + filename+".jpg");
        return response.build();

}
```