# Consume web service which produces stream (streams some binary data as output)

Tags: java, rest, swagger

I have a REST Java service which returns a file as a stream. It's similar to the output approaches described here:

[Input and Output binary streams using JERSEY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496209/input-and-output-binary-streams-using-jersey)

I also use `StreamingOuput` as described above.

I now wonder now how to call this method on the client side. I use Swagger but I am not very good with it, and I have no idea how to call my method.

Currently in the web service I have defined

`@ApiOperation(value = "Export file from the database", response = File.class)`

but I doubt this `File.class` is a good idea here.

Do I need to modify this response type? What is a good way of calling my service?

When I call my service from the Swagger UI interface I see these response headers.

`{
  "date": "Sun, 27 Aug 2017 11:14:20 GMT",
  "content-disposition": "attachment; filename=\"DealerTexts.xlsx\"",
  "x-powered-by": "Servlet/3.1 JSP/2.3 (  Java/Oracle Corporation/1.8)",
  "transfer-encoding": "chunked",
  "server": "",
  "content-type": "application/octet-stream"
}`

In the response body it gives me a link which I can click and download the file generated by the web service. So my question is just how I can call this same thing from Java code on the client side.

Comment: The swagger codegen should generare the client code for you. Anyway it should be a simple HTTP GET request in Java.

Comment: @MarioSantini  Right, but what do I define on the client side as response attribute of @ApiOperation?   `response = File.class` is probably not good so this confuses Swagger to generate the right code on the client side, I think.

Comment: I'm not expert of swagger but googling I found this: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/1876. You should try to write an example in code and test it to see what happen. If you get an error update your question accordingly.

Comment: @MarioSantini Yes, I managed to get it working myself with "byte.class". I didn't find that link though, I just did it with trial and error and with some intuition. So your link now confirms my approach. I am all set now. Thank you.